# How to connect a servo feedback potentiometer?

Tags: gpio, servo

I've taken apart an old RC car and have been trying to get my Raspberry Pi to run the car.

At this point, I'm able to control the rear drive motor. The motor is connected to a L298N H-Bridge module. The H-Bridge is connected to a 12v battery and can be controlled via the Pi.

My issue is figuring out how to control the steering motor. It is a servomotor like this [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Servo.jpg)

I believe the motor in the servo is a standard [130 dc motor](https://www.bananarobotics.com/shop/image/cache/data/sku/BR/0/1/0/0/7/BR010077-Pololu-130-Size-Brushed-DC-Motor-3-12V/Pololu-130-Size-Brushed-DC-Motor-3-12V-600x600.jpg), which has a red and black wire attached.

The servo also has 4 wires connected to it - green, yellow, brown and white. I imagine these are to connect the feedback potentiometer.

How do I connect the wires coming from the servo/feedback potentiometer to the Pi?

Many thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a Pi question.  You may be better off asking on a RC hobby site.

Comment: Probably better to find a modern pwm controlled servo and replace the one in the car.

Comment: The steering servo has 6 wires?

Comment: 4 wires to a potentiometer sounds strange.  At this point I'd try probing: put your multimeter into continuity test mode and see if any of the wires are connected to the same point.  Then try putting the meter into resistance measuring mode and measure the resistance between pairs of wires and repeat with the steering moved manually to various positions.  That info should help figure out what each wire is connected to.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I will just go ahead and purchase a regular servo for simplicity.